# Can't connect to default gateway of WiFi router - but can connect to network?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-router, wifi-configuration

I'm having a tiny problem: 
I'm using a Huawei b260a 3G router as a WiFi router. I've got the SIM card disconnected and an Ethernet (RJ-45) going into the back of it.

The WiFi part of it works fine. I can connect to a network it broadcasts using a password on the machine's back. This is all great.

Not so great is the fact that I can't connect to the default gateway 192.168.0.1, 192.168.0.0 or 192.168.1.1.

I'm not sure why I can't do this.

I've scoured the manual but it doesn't help much. Another problem is hard resetting the router as it's provider's firmware on it, so you can't really reset it.

Oh, and I'm trying to connect to 192.168.1.1 on my phone as my desktop doesn't have a WiFi card.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

> Not so great is the fact that I can't connect to the default gateway 192.168.0.1 or 192.168.0.0

The default gateway for this router should be 192.168.1.1, not 192.168.0.1.

Comment: Hmm. Well that's really odd. Welcome and I hope you find a solution... :-\

Comment: yup, well I haven't found one yet and that's why I asked here; to no avail :)